# Will a failed QUORUM write be hinted?

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-2.0, datastax-enterprise

Given a 3-node cluster where a QUORUM write fails due to two nodes temporarily being down; If the two failing nodes come back up (within hinted handoff window), will the write propagate to the two other nodes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What will happen if write failed in cassandra cluster when using QUORUM CL?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30935174/what-will-happen-if-write-failed-in-cassandra-cluster-when-using-quorum-cl)

Answer (score 0):

In a 3 node cluster QUORUM will be 2.

CONSISTENCY level is number of nodes that should acknowledge the Read/Write operation.

When using CL of QUORUM and if 2 nodes are down, then the write/read request will fail.
There will be no role hinted handoff here.
Hinted handoff is used only when CL is achieved but the RF is not met;In this case if node comes up in handoff window then hints will be propogate to this nodes